# Preloading view in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am doing a recyclerview with different viewtypes using the viewholder pattern.
As one of my views I have a graphView and the load-time makes my recyclerview stutter when scrolling past it.
I have tried initializing the graph in onCreateViewhodler and it gave a little but not enough :-(

Is there any way of preloading the view or only reloading under certain conditions?

onCreateViewholder

```
  @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ...
    switch(viewType){

        case 0:{
            ...
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.today_graph, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new GraphViewholder(v);
            chart = new TodayChartView (mContext, v);
            chart.createGraph(item);
            break;
        }
```

onBindViewholder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0: {
            ...
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            GraphViewholder graphViewholder = (GraphViewholder) holder;
            BindGraphViewHolder(graphViewholder, position, chart);
            break;
        }
```

BindViewholder

```
private void BindGraphViewHolder(GraphViewholder holder, int position, TodayChartView chart) {
    if(holder.itemView==null){
        ((ViewGroup)holder.itemView).addView(chart.getView());
    }
}
```

Viewholder

```
public static class GraphViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public GraphViewholder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}
```